# Confusion with ' int*s = new int[i]; ' and ' int*f = new int; '

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int t, i;
cin >> i;

int*s = new int[i];

for (t = 0; t < i; t++) {
    s[t] = t;//How??
    cout << s[t] << "_" << &s[t] << endl;
}

int*f = new int;
*f = t; // Whhhhhy???
delete f;
delete[] s
```

I declared an array type and an integer as dynamic memory.

While I can assign any ordinary integer value to *f (and pointer value for f),
it keeps warning me when assigning an integer value to *s[t].

I have no idea as to why.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: And.. What you are confused about?

Comment: The *reason* we say you could use one, is because this is a set of problems that really are best answered with a book, since the authors have the time and space to give you an explanation of things like initialization, object lifetime, and management of memory and other resources.

Comment: Also missing: `delete[] s`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you get a warning is because `s[t]` is shorthand for `*(s+t)`, so `*s[t]` is shorthand for `**(s+t)`. That's one too many `*`.

Comment: Actually that should be error, not warning if compiler would be used properly.

Comment: @Slava: The standard merely describes it as a "diagnostic".

Answer (score 0):

The [] operator includes an implicit '*'.   Assign your value to s[t] rather than *s[t]